Does importing ES6 module initialize variable?
// util.ts
const sessionAttr = {}

const session = {
    setAttribute(k: string | number, v: any) {
        sessionAttr[k] = v
    },
    getAttribute(k: string | number) {
        return sessionAttr[k]
    },
    removeAttribute(k: string) {
        delete sessionAttr[k]
    }
}

export const Util = {
    session,
}

// A.vue
import { Util } from '@/util'

Util.session.setAttribute('ssACNo', 'someString')

// B.vue
import { Util } from '@/util'

Util.session.getAttribute('ssACNo') // 'someString' ..?

When changing route A => B,
sometimes Util.session.getAttribute('ssACNo') return 'someString',
but sometimes return undefined.
I cannot figure out why happen, what difference..
I expected that session variable will keep the data while moving a route to other route.
But maybe when other route import same module again, all variable of module has been initialize I thought.
Is this right? please let me know why, and how can I keep the data while moving route?

Have you tried to turn the section functions into async and call it by using await Util.session....?

session functions are just setter and getter so 'await' and 'async' change nothing

the main problem is sometimes - and you haven't shown code that demonstrates the issue

It's the order of the evaluation of the modules that matters, it's undetermined in case of lazily loaded modules. This is common for route views but you didn't show it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Module state can also be affected by hot reload. It's unknown what's the context for this code, it could mean different things with 
I think you right @EstusFlask .
I am using Vite and that 'sometimes' only happen when page hot reloaded by Vite.
Thanks you

You seem to already using a global store, although it's non-reactive which may cause inconvenience with vue, like you can't watch for changes in case there are race conditions in your case. You can do the same thing in a more straightforward way with pinia, and it already provides the support for hot reload https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/hot-module-replacement.html
